How to use datatable, in table that append by jquery?
Im still new in jquery, i created a table in jquery and after the table was appended I used datatable, but the datatable had an error I don't know what caused the error.
Here is my code:
HTML:
    <div class="card-body pt-5">
            <form action="" method="POST" id="approval_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @method('POST')
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="approval_eseverance" class="table table-hover table-row-bordered table-striped border gy-7 gs-7">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="fw-semibold fs-6 text-gray-800 border-bottom-2 border-gray-200">
                             <th class="min-w-100px" >a</th>
                                <th class="min-w-150px">b</th>
                                <th class="min-w-200px">c</th>
                                <th class="min-w-150px ">d</th>
                                <th class=" min-w-150px">e</th>
                                <th>f</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>(the tr td in tbody)
</tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                </form>

JS:
       $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
     new DataTable('#approval_eseverance', {
        "dom": '<"top"lf>rt<"bottom"ip>',
        fixedColumns: {
            left: 3,
        },
        scrollX: true,
        layout: {
            bottomEnd: {
                paging: {
                    boundaryNumbers: false
                }
            }
        }
    });
 $(document).on('click', '.approval_detail', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // alert("test");
        var request_id = $(this).data('request-id');
$.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('detail') }}",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                request_id: request_id,
            },
            success: function (res) {
                $('#approval_form').empty();
 var table = $('#approval_form');
var table_detail = "";
table_detail +=
                        table_detail +=
                        '<div id="create-form-pkwt" class="create-form table-responsive" autocomplete="off">';
                    table_detail +=
                        '<table class="table tb_create table-bordered" id="create-pkwt">';
                    table_detail += '<thead>';
                    table_detail +=
                        '<tr class="fw-bold fs-6 text-gray-800"><th style="white-space:nowrap" class="text-center" rowspan="3">No</th>';
                    table_detail +=
                        '<th style="white-space:nowrap" class="text-center" rowspan="3">Employee Number</th>';
                    table_detail +=
                        '<th style="white-space:nowrap" class="text-center" rowspan="3">Name</th>';
table_detail += '</tr>';
 table_detail += '</thead>';
  table_detail += ' <tbody>';
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                        table_detail +=
                            '<tr><td class="text-center" style="white-space:nowrap">'+res[i].sub+'</td>';
                        table_detail +=
                            '<td class="text-center" style="white-space:nowrap"><input type="hidden" id="pernr_create-pkwt' +
                            res[i].sub + '" name="pernr[]" value="' + res[i].number+
                            '">' + res[i].number+ '</td>';
                        table_detail +=
                            '<td class="text-center headcol3" style="white-space:nowrap"><input type="hidden" id="ename_create-pkwt' +
                            res[i].sub + '" name="ename[' + res[i].number+
                            ']" value="' + res[i].name+ '">' + res[i].ename + '</td></tr>';
}
 table_detail += '</tbody>';
                    table_detail += '</table></div>';
                    table.append(table_detail);
                        $("#create-pkwt").DataTable({
                            scrollY:        "300px",
                            scrollX:        true,
                            scrollCollapse: true,
                            fixedColumns:   {
                                left: 2
                            }
                        });

In js i empty the table in html and append the new table, the table append and show well good but the datatable is error.
i got this error, went I use
$("#create-pkwt").DataTable({
                            scrollY:        "300px",
                            scrollX:        true,
                            scrollCollapse: true,
                            fixedColumns:   {
                                left: 2
                            }
                        });


Can anyone help me
(edit: I remove the rowspan,colspan and the datatable works, is the rowspan cannot be use with datatable? is there any solution? because I want to make the column like this)


If I recall, setting '0' error in datatables means there's a mismatch between columns and data.  Eg you have fixedColumns: .. 2 but looks like there's only 1 column

Actually, there were a lot of td, because it was too long  I only wrote 1, sorry

No worries - that issue can be ruled out.   Though could still be related.

You say that, but your updated markup is:  <tr><th></th></tr> <th></th> <th></th> - the </tr> is in the wrong place

ok wait let me check first

sorry i place the tr in wrong place, i already edit the code
